# Restrict who can see my profile in facebook

Tags: facebook, profile, restrict

First i want to start that i even don't want to bother anybody but i just don't know what to do. I was looking for help in alot of places, and i found almost nothing. I just don't know what to do any more so i am asking here some help and any suggestation will be appritiated, any kind of help. I'am even willing to send some petty cash to a resolve to my problem.

So here is the deal - i want to make a restriction to my facebook account - but in a very specific way. There are some people witch all the time rub there noses in my work, and my things like personal life and even sometimes when i go to take a shit. There are friends of me on facebook, and i want to make somehow a restriction of what they can see in my posts, my account, in one simple sentence, restrict everything they can see. I am sure, here you will ask me - why i just simply don't block them, remove from my frinds and so on. The problem is that some of this people are members of my family, and if i do that, in a hour or maybe two there will be(excuse me) fucking hullabaloo to the sky. "Why he did that, he is my cousin!" "He don't respect the familly", and alot of other shits like that. So i hope you undearstand now the delicasy of the situation. So the main question is, is there a way to make this restriction without removing them from my friends, and without have to block them. Any facebook tool ? Some sort of a application, anything ?

Here i want to point that, I don't take any drugs, i'am not a paranoid schizophrenic, even the oposit the people who are doing this to me, are calling me like that, but i guess the are the ones.

Thx in advance for each answer i will recieve.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press the arrow in the top right on your facebook page and go to settings
On the left side you should go into protection of personal information and change what your friends can see.
You can even go into timeline and tagging and again change the permissions for your friends

Comment: Just, before they are going to close this, i want to say big damn thank you